# Browser returning wrong content in case of HTTP 304

Tags: google-chrome, http, rest, firefox

The following testcase causes Chrome 34.0.1847.116m and Firefox 28 to return (what I consider to be) incorrect responses after receiving HTTP 304.

1. Client requests `GET http://example.com/companies/1/` using `Accept: text/html`
2. Server returns representation `A` and some headers.
3. The Javascript in the HTML causes the client to request `GET http://example.com/companies/1/` using `Accept: application/vnd.com.mycompany.something+json; version=1`
4. Server returns representation `B` and different headers.
5. Now... reload the page by hitting F5.
6. Steps 1-4 repeat, except that the server returns `HTTP 304` for all requests.
7. Step 1 returns `A` and the first set of headers, as expected, but step 4 **also** returns `A` and the first set of headers, which is unexpected.

Meaning, the browser is returning the same cached response (body and headers) in spite of the fact that the request `Accept` has changed. I am expecting the last request to return `B` and the second set of headers.

**Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in Chrome and Firefox?**

Comment: Is the server sending `Vary: Accept`?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky, you nailed it. I actually figured this out independently a few minutes ago by reading http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-26#section-4.1. Please post a formal answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done.  The handling of Vary is, of course messier than it would be if everyone just followed the spec... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record:

Technically if the response depends on request headers the server needs to send the corresponding `Vary` header in the response so caches know to include those request headers in the cache key.

In practice browsers include some headers in the cache key automatically to work around broken servers (e.g. very few servers send `Vary: Cookie`, even when they should), but `Content-Type` is not a header commonly abused like that, so browsers don't do anything special there.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

According to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-26#page-6 and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-26#section-4.1 if the response is subject to negotiation, servers MUST return a `Vary` header. This header indicates what headers were involved in the negotiation process. The absence of this header implies that the response is based purely on the URI.

In my case, returning `Vary: Accept` fixed the problem.